# 18.04 ubuntu sqlitebrowser doesn't start

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, db-browser-sqlite

I'm new to ubuntu and I cannot make db browser to launch, it seems to me that i am missing libraries, but i don't know how to add them because I am a noob. 
when i type sqlitebrowser in terminal I get:

> sqlitebrowser: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Network.so.5:    cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

when I type which sqlitebrowser I get:

> /usr/bin/sqlitebrowser

when I type ldd 'which sqlitebrowser' I get:

> linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd22d58000)
>       libQt5Network.so.5 => not found
>       libQt5Xml.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0x00007fb17b1e0000)
>       libsqlcipher.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlcipher.so.0 (0x00007fb17af09000)
>       libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007fb17ac9a000)
>       libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
>       libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
>       libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
>       libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb17a90c000)
>       libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb17a56e000)
>       libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb17a356000)
>       libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb179f65000)
>       libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
>       libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fb179aed000)
>       libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb1798ce000)
>       libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb1796ca000)
>       /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb17bb50000)
>       libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
>       libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
>       libQt5Core.so.5 => not found

So I reason that I am missing those libQt5 things but I have no idea how to add them. 
Will appreciate any help !

Comment: I have exactly the same case when trying to run the sqlite browser from within the WSL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Comment: that didn't help :<

Comment: What did that command output? Did it install something or did it say already installed?

Comment: it installed some stuff :|

Comment: It could be that the libraries are there, but the versioned filenames for them are not. Try `sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev`. Does that help with the `ldd` output at all?